# Issue running query in prolog with list and predicate

Tags: prolog, logic

Currently trying to create a library recommendation system in prolog for a college assignment and being quite new to prolog I'm quite lost and was wondering if I could have some of this explained to me in fine detail.
Here are my facts and rules currently:

```
book(after_dark, haruki_murakami,fiction,182).
book(python, charlie, revision, 560).
book(nt_bible, sams, reference, 480).
book(monty_python, cleese, comedy, 300).

buildLibrary(Lib) :- findall(book(Title, Author, Genre, Size), book(Title, Author,
Genre, Size), Lib).

holiday(B,L) :- //this should take the list formed in buildLibrary along with a variable that represents a book 
                //and is true if and only if its genre is comedy or fiction and less than 400 pages
```

Expected input: 

`buildLibrary(L)
holidays(book(after_dark,haruki_murakami,fiction,182),L)`

Ideally this should return true as it meets the requirements outlined

How do I go about setting the rule for holiday? Once I know how to do this I feel like I can get it working, I've tried multiple things and they've all returned errors in SWL prolog, once again thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I correctly understand your implementation then you could do something like:

```
holiday(B,L) :- buildLibrary(Lib), check(L,B).


check(book(X, Y, Genre, Size),[book(X, Y, Genre, Size)|_]):-
                    (Genre = comedy ;Genre = fiction), Size < 400.
check(B,[book(_, _, Genre, Size)|T]):-
                     dif(Genre,comedy),dif(Genre,fiction), check(B,T).
```

Comment: Well in the assignment my lecturer states: 

"Your holiday, revision, literary and leisure predicates should take 2 parameters; a
“query” book (with as yet unknown (variable) title and author) and a library (a list of
books). It will go through the list and evaluates to true if the book at the head of the
list is the appropriate type of book (in which case it will match the title and author of
the library book with the “query” book)."

However, I don't know how to represent the "query" as a rule.

Comment: Can you post an example input- expected output about the holiday predicate??

Comment: Updated my question, hopefully that makes it clearer

Comment: This is going to sound so stupid, so if it is I apologize. When I'm running the query in swl prolog, can I just set `B = book(after_dark,haruki_murakami,fiction,182)` When I'm using the `holiday(B,L)` predicate? So instead it would look like:`holiday(book(after_dark,haruki_murakami,fiction,182), L)`

Comment: of course, like B=book(...), holiday(B,L)... nothing stupid at all!!

Comment: Cool! Thanks for your help then!!